# Fabry Perot Etalon - changing wavelength and plate distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, interference, diffraction, interferometry

Given reflectivity $R = 0.75$, an etalon is used as an interference filter, transmitting light of wavelength $4.3\mu m$ at normal incidence. The full width half maximum is about $\Delta \lambda = 0.2 \mu m$. Find the initial spacing of plate.

(a) Find the spacing of the plate.

(b) Find the change in mirror spacing to shift the centre wavelength to $4.5\mu m$.

(c) The spacing is now fixed at a value that gives maximum intensity at $4.3\mu m$ at normal incidence. The angle of incidence is changed to $17.5^o$, find the wavelength of light transmitted.

(d) Find a wavelength shorter and longer than $4.3\mu m$ that gives maximum intensity at normal incidence.

I'm quite confused by this question, as usually either the spacing or wavelength is fixed...now you can even change the wavelength of light merely by changing the spacing?!

**Attempt**

(a) Intensity is given by: $I = I_0 \frac{1}{1 + \frac{4R}{(1-R)^2}sin^2(\frac{\delta}{2})}$. At $I = \frac{I_0}{2}$,

$$ \delta = \frac{1-R}{\sqrt R}  $$

Thus FWHM $\Delta \delta$ = $2 \times \delta = \frac{2(1-R)}{\sqrt R} $

Using $\delta = 2nd = \frac{4\pi d}{\lambda}$, $\Delta \lambda = \frac{4\pi d}{\lambda^2}\Delta \lambda$.

Using n = 1, $d = \frac{\Delta \delta}{\Delta \lambda} \frac{\lambda^2}{4\pi} = 4.25 \mu m$.

(b) Condition of maxima is $2d cos\theta = m\lambda$. Central maxima is given by $m_0 = \frac{2d}{\lambda} \approx 2$. (Quite a lousy etalon right? Only able to see 2 fringes)

Now for the same value of $m_0$, we want to increase $\lambda$, so naturally the LHS term $d$ must increase as well.
$$\Delta d = \frac{m_0}{2}\Delta \lambda = \frac{d}{\lambda}\Delta \lambda = +0.2 \mu m $$

(c) Again fixing $m_0$, and now the spacing is the original $4.25\mu m$.
$$2d cos (17.5^o) = m_0 \lambda$$

$$\lambda = 4.05 \mu m$$

The wavlength is now shorter! At this point I have no idea what I'm doing anymore, how can the wavelength be changed?!

(d) Since it's either m = 1 or m = 2,

$$m = \frac{2d}{\lambda} $$

For $m=1$, $\lambda = 2d = 8.5 \mu m$

For $m=2$, $\lambda = d = 4.25 \mu m$

I would really appreciate if anyone could explain what's going on, as I'm pretty much confused..

Comment: You can change the wavelength of maximum transmission by changing the spacing.  Imagine a tunable laser, or broadband source. Does that help?

Comment: I think that (a) is assuming the material of the etalon has an index of refraction *n* other than 1. You need to find *n* that explains why the thickness 4.25 um gives transmission at 4.3 um. Then you can figure how to adjust thickness to get the transmission wavelength you want.

Comment: @garyp Ok, so the output wavelength can be varied from the spacing - for center spot $2d = m_0\lambda$. Does $m_0$ change at all? Since $m_0$ was determined by the previous spacing and wavelength

Comment: @ThePhoton Sorry I don't see how the refractive index helps at all, as it only modifies the equation to be $2nd = m\lambda$

Comment: *m* is an integer. Without considering *n*, you wouldn't find an integer *m* that gives 2 * (4.25) = *m* * 4.3.

Comment: @ThePhoton There is actually a part before this question, which asked us to find the spacing between the gap. I assumed n = 1 for that. I'll upload the earlier part now